# Geocode the address written in native language using English letters

Tags: python, r, google-maps, geocoding

Friends,

I am analyzing some texts. My requirement is to gecode the address written in English letters of a different native language.

```
Ex: chandpur market ke paas, village gorthaniya, UP, INDIA
```

In above sentence words like, "ke paas" --> is a HINDI word (Indian national language), which means "near" in English and "chandapur market" is a noun (can be ignored for conversion)

Now my challenge is to convert such thousands of words to english and identify the street name and geo code it. Unfortunately, i do not have postal code or exact address.

Can you any one please help here?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's [geocode api](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis) supports Hindi, so you don't necessarily have to translate it to English. Here's an example using my `googleway` package (in R) specifying the `language = "hi"` argument.

You'll need an API key to use the Google API through `googleway`

```
library(googleway)

set_key("your_api_key")

res <- google_geocode(address = "village gorthaniya, UP, INDIA",
               language = "hi")

geocode_address(res)
# [1] "गोर्थानिया, उत्तर प्रदेश 272181, भारत"

geocode_coordinates(res)
#         lat      lng
# 1 26.85848 82.50099

geocode_address_components(res)
#   long_name short_name                                  types
# 1    गोर्थानिया      गोर्थानिया                    locality, political
# 2       बस्ती        बस्ती  administrative_area_level_2, political
# 3    उत्तर प्रदेश      उ॰ प्र॰  administrative_area_level_1, political
# 4       भारत         IN                      country, political
# 5    272181     272181                             postal_code
```